# How to place a file in my bundle's resource directory?

Tags: xcode

I have a .html file that needs to go into my iPhone app's bundle resource directory.  I tried FIle -> New -> Resource but nothing seemed to fit the bill.

Right now I'm using a UIWebView loadRequest and have the "pathForResource:@"help.htm"... it crashes when it can't find help.htm.  If I put this in a Resource directoyr, I believe I can still use the same code without any directory qualifiers.

How do I do this?

UPDATE:

Here is the UIWebView code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"helpSegue"])  {

        [slWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp.htm" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];


    }
    else 
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"reportSegue"]) {
            NSLog(@"reportSegue");
        }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
```

Comment: Can you please post all of your UIWebView code?

Comment: Aren't all files automatically copied to the Resources directory if they aren't source files?

Comment: Updated original post again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
[slWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp.htm" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

You need to omit the extension from the file name since it is specified in a separate parameter:

```
[slWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp" ofType:@"htm"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Then just add the "iHelp.htm" file to the project as normal making sure it is marked as included the applications target.

Just to be sure, try right clicking your app in the "Products" group and select "Reveal in Finder". Then right click the .app bundle (which is just a folder) and select reveal contents to see what's actually included. If you don't see your "iHelp.htm" file it means it is not marked as a member of the target. Find and select the "iHelp.htm" file in Xcode then open the utilities view. Look under the "Target Membership section and make sure the checkbox for your application target is checked.

**Update**
What you see with the above change is this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp" ofType:@"htm"]
```

Causes a search in the app bundle for "iHelp.htm" which is returning the path of the htm file where before it was returning nil since it couldn't find it. (Before you were looking for "iHelp.htm.html" which didn't exist. The next part of your problem is figuring out why this path is not properly converted to a URLRequest. You have a lot of inlining, which I personally love, but to correctly debug you may want to break it out into separate variables temporarily.

```
NSString *iHelpPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp" ofType:@"htm"];
NSLog(@"iHelpPath = %@", iHelpPath);
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:iHelpPath];
NSLog(@"fileURL = %@", fileURL);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
NSLog(@"request = %@", request);
```

And see what that gives you.

Comment: I did as you suggested, removing the .htm, and changing the parameter to htm, and at least it didn't crash... however, it didn't display the file either.  Changed the parameter back to "html" and it crashed.  How do I mark the file as "included in the applications target?  (btw, Location is set to "Relative to Group")

Comment: It looks like [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iHelp" ofType:@"htm"] is finding your resource which is why it no longer crashes. Let me post another answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: Can't post all of the code here anymore... look here:  http://pastebin.com/d4REAbKL

Comment: ok it looks like everything is fine as far as constructing the URL request. Try to "open /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C45F75FD-9199-4A62-B51F-1CC0C62E3135/SurveyorLeveling-I.app/iHelp.htm" from the cmd line and see if Safari loads it ok.

Comment: One other thing to understand is that loading URL requests are asynchronous operations. You probably need to register a callback or listener to know when it is finished loading.

Comment: yep, but none of the images are there... will have to create an images folder in the app to fix that... regarding the callback/listener... it should load almost instantaneously, right?

Comment: You probably want to follow the UIWebViewDelegate Protocol and listen for the "– webViewDidFinishLoad:" callback.

Comment: Oh, I see! You are looking for the images to show. Yes you need to either alter the location of the images in the html file or recreate the structure. I forget how to do this but I believe you can just make use of the "copy bundle resources" build phase to push an images folder into your bundle. Click on the project icon in the left hand view of Xcode, select the "Build Phases" tab and try to drag/drop your images folder into the "copy bundle resources" section.

Comment: Yes it should load almost instantly but it's still an asynchronous operation and you need to code that way. Any code that needs to run after the view is loaded must go in the callback of a UIWebViewDelegate Protocol implementation.

Comment: Ahhh... the actual .htm is not showing in the app... it does in Firefox... do you suppose the images are the issue?  In other words, if anything is missing, nothing will show?  The way I built this is in Storyboard I have a UIViewController with a UIWebView sitting in it.  Could that be the problem?  (I'm grasping at straws now)

Comment: The htm is finding it's way into your app. The output from your log statements along with the disappearance of crashes confirms that. Your problem appears to be the images not showing because the browser is looking for them in a folder(s) that do not exist. Try to include the image folder in the copy bundle resources build phase as I mentioned above.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem... I found this: http://www.howtomakeiphoneapps.com/uiwebview-tutorial/239/...

I do NOT have a controller for the UIView that contains the UIWebView.  Would that cause the problem? (want to check before I make the changes)